# In ruby, can you execute assert_equal and other asserts while in irb?

Tags: ruby, testunit

Can you execute assert_equal from within irb? This does not work.

```
require 'test/unit'
assert_equal(5,5)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sure you can!

```
require 'test/unit'
extend Test::Unit::Assertions
assert_equal 5, 5                # <= nil
assert_equal 5, 6                # <= raises AssertionFailedError
```

What's going on is that all the assertions are methods in the Test::Unit::Assertions module.  Extending that module from inside irb makes those methods available as class methods on `main`, which allows you to call them directly from your irb prompt.  (Really, calling `extend SomeModule` in any context will put the methods in that module somewhere you can call them from the same context - `main` just happens to be where you are by default.)

Also, since the assertions were designed to be run from within a `TestCase`, the semantics might be a little different than expected: instead of returning true or false, it returns nil or raises an error.

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks for the quick response. Just needed to remove the quotes after the extend statement.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I get for not testing it out.  :-)  Fixed and filled in a little more explanation (for you or any future viewers).

Comment: If you want it to return true/false in IRB, just use == instead.  5 == 5 # => true    5 == 6 # => false

Answer (score 9):

The Correct answer is ,

```
require 'test/unit/assertions'

include Test::Unit::Assertions
```

Comment: Wow. great!! after searching all over the internet. I found this solution.@Nilesh

Answer (score 6):

You can also do

```
raise "Something's gone wrong" unless 5 == 5
```

I don't use `assert` in code that's being tested, I only use it in test code.